# Troubleshoot i18n YAML in Rails the Easy Way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

I waste tons of time trying to construct the the proper yaml for translating text and labels in Rails.

Is there an easy way to pinpoint what path I should use in the YAML to provide the translation?

As an example, I am using a nested simple_form with this form erb:

```
<%= f.input :birth_date, as:'string' %>
```

The label I get is `Birth date` and I am assuming is just coming from the model attribute.

When I debug that line and type `f.object_name` I get

```
=> "user_wizard[children_attributes]
```

Here's my YAML

```
en-US:
  simple_form:
    labels:
      user_wizard:
        children_attributes:
          birth_date: "Name Date or Expected Date"
```

Is there a sure-fire way to log, print, probe, watch, render or query that will give the (or one) exact path I need in almost any situation? Not just simple_form or a model attribute but for error messages, buttons, mailers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

We have had tons of issues with the i18n key management as well, that's why we have decided to go down a different road and display the whole key name, with a possibility to edit it in place as well. We feel that this solves the problem of finding the correct key name and filling it. Check out our solution, [PhraseApp](https://phraseapp.com) and especially our [In-Context Editor](https://phraseapp.com/en/features/in-context-editor).

To summarize: The best thing might be to expose the key name through code. We have built our own solution, but you probably can do it with a little monkey patch to i18n as well.

Comment: PhraseApp is a complete solution. Thanks for pointing it out. I am looking for something a little more limited in scope.